# SQL : Return joint most frequent values from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table named customerOrders.

```
ID    user    order
1      1        2
2      1        3
3      1        1
4      2        1
5      1        5
6      2        4
7      3        1
8      6        2
9      2        2
10     2        3
```

I want to return to users with most orders. Currently, I have the following QUERY:

```
SELECT user, COUNT(user) AS UsersWithMostOrders
FROM customerOrders
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY UsersWithMostOrders DESC;
```

This returns me all the values grouped by total orders like.

```
user     UsersWithMostOrders
1               4
2               4
3               1
6               1
```

I only want to return the users with most orders. In my case that would be user 1 and 2 since both of them have 4 orders. If I use TOP 1 or LIMIT, it will only return the first user. If I use TOP 2, it will only work in this scenario, it will return invalid data when top two users have different count of orders.

**Required Result**

```
user    UsersWithMostOrders
 1              4
 2              4
```

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL, MSSQL, etc. And providing the version of SQL would be beneficial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`TOP 1 WITH TIES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
  [user], COUNT(*) AS UsersWithMostOrders
FROM customerOrders
GROUP BY [user]
ORDER BY UsersWithMostOrders DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9badaf685090faa5e4ebc7f0f6df01da).
Results:

```
> user | UsersWithMostOrders
> ---: | ------------------:
>    1 |                   4
>    2 |                   4
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
Should work with most versions of SQL.

```
select * 
from (
  select    *, 
          rank() over(order by numOrders desc) as rrank
  from (
    select `user`, count(*) as numOrders
    from customerOrders
    group by `user`
  ) summed 
) ranked 
where rrank = 1
```

Play around with the code [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4W3P8AW8gszVBE9jU56UT/3)

**Option 2**
If your version of SQL allows window functions (`with`), here is a much more readable solution which does the same thing

```
with summed as (
    select `user`, count(*) as numOrders
    from customerOrders
    group by `user` 
),
ranked as (
    select *, 
           rank() over(order by numOrders desc) as rrank
    from summed 
)
select * 
from ranked 
where rrank = 1
```

Play around with the code [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4W3P8AW8gszVBE9jU56UT/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to attain this Req:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT [user], COUNT(user) AS UsersWithMostOrders
FROM @T
GROUP BY [user])

SELECT M.* from CTE M
INNER JOIN ( SELECT
MAX(UsersWithMostOrders) AS MaximumOrders FROM CTE) S ON 
M.UsersWithMostOrders=S.MaximumOrders
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Oracle Query can help:

```
WITH test_table AS
(
SELECT user, COUNT(order) AS total_order , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY 
total_order desc) AS rank_orders  FROM customerOrders
GROUP BY user 
)
select * from test_table where rank_orders = 1
```